# highlight gridview cell by header and row values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I was able to highlight a cell based on field name and criteria of cell in that column. Now I want to do the same thing but also consider the row value from the second column as well. Example below

Gender | Part Number | Small | Medium | Large

Men    | C-888-TVN   |    5  |   6    |   9

Men    | C-777-TV4   |    7  |   7    |   8

So if I want to highlight the '7' in the C-777-TV4 row and  under the Medium size how would I go about doing both criteria. This is not based on a number value criteria just the name of the header "Medium" and string value in the part number row "C-777-TV4".

Here is the new code that i'm getting an out of range error:

`Protected Sub gridStock_HtmlRowPrepared(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs) Handles gridStock.HtmlRowPrepared
    If e.RowType <> GridViewRowType.Data Then
    Return
    End If
    Dim name As String = e.GetValue("CorePN").ToString()
    If name = "777-M-MBL" Then
    e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
    End Sub`

Getting the error at e.Row.Cells(10).Backcolor

Comment: how about using `row.Cell[3]` ?

Comment: how do I state getting the row with C-777-TV4 row. Then I can retrieve the third column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see more code of yours. Here is what I thought:

```
If row.Cell(1).Text = "C-777-TV4" Then
     e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan
End If
```

Comment: thanks for the response.                                                                        `Sub gridStock_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Cells(5).Text = "777-M-CIT"
            e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan


        End If

    End Sub'

Comment: it does make sense but i'm still not seeing any difference. I tried using both the rowcreated event and the rowdatabound event and both do not work in my scenario.

Comment: @SouthernGentleman if you can post all of your code, I can help more I guess.

Comment: Protected Sub gridStock_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs)
        If e.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "C-777-TV4" Then
                e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End Sub    'I used the same logic for both the rowcreated and rowdatabound events

Comment: did you use debugger? I believe rowdatabound is the correct place to have your code.

Comment: @SouthernGentleman can you post this part of the code (and even more) in the original post?

Comment: I did debug it and there were no errors. I changed the code a little and Now I am getting a "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index" error. There error is on line 640:
Line 638:        Dim name As String = e.GetValue("CorePN").ToStr<wbr ></wbr>ing()
Line 639:        If name = "CIT-88D-2015A" Then
Line 640:            e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
Line 641:        End If
Line 642:    End Sub

Comment: @SouthernGentleman can you post this part of the code (and even more) in the original post?

Comment: @SouthernGentleman does it work when you have this istead : `e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red`

Comment: Yes the entire row is highlighted when I don't call a row cell index. but I want only one cell under the medium size. For some reason its not working. So my parameters are "CorePN" column and then the row for part number "C-777-TV4" and then 5 cells to the right. So its the adjacent row under the size Medium.

Comment: exactly, that is why I wanted you to try this. Let me see what is wrong with cell..

Comment: can you try this ` e.Row.Cells(5).Style.Add("background-color", "#ff0000")` btw in your code you have `Cells(10)` so you have 11 columns?

Comment: Sorry still getting the argument is out of range of valid values Paremeter name: Index. Is it because i'm looking for a cell index and should look under a column name instead. Not sure how to implement that with the code.

Comment: I fixed it the solution, I just used a different event. But thanks again for the help.

Comment: Oh finally ! Glad to help!